# How to get month/day to compare with another month/day without year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select month/day to compare with another month/day to determine which day is greater.  For example, to compare 2/28 with 3/18.  What would be the date format I can use to compare the days.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: You need to edit your question so that it is clear what you need. waiting for people to provide answers and then telling them why it wont work is not a useful way to provide additional information (2* answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can convert dates to strings using the `convert` function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

The format you want to use is `mm/dd/yy`, which is style `1` on the `convert` function. Then you can simply take the `left` 5 characters:

```
select left(convert(char(8),YourDate,1),5) as mm_dd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to display the month and day, you can use this:

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME2 = '02/28/2015'

SELECT CAST(MONTH(@myDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DAY(@myDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Comment: with using VARCHAR(2), am I able to compare with other day?  If I compare 2/28 with 3/18 in the store procedure, would it compare which day is greater?

Comment: You'd only put this in Varchar format for display purposes.  All comparisons should be done in a date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DATE,1),5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format function?

```
select format(getdate(),'dd/MM')
```

Comment: my sql server is 2008 and it is not compatible with format function

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DATEPART function to get the day of year for your dates.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20150130';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '20141225';

SELECT 
    @StartDate AS StartDate, 
    DATEPART(DY, @StartDate) AS StartDy, 
    @EndDate AS EndDate, 
    DATEPART(DY, @EndDate) AS EndDy;
```